# How can I solve routing in HMVC?

Tags: url-routing, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I am working on a cms project which will be used to publish news sites. I am using i18n plugin for multilingual issues. the problem is at routing. I have module called `news` and method `page` in it and route is set as

```
$route['page/test'] = 'news/page/1';
```

this works without problem when i go to

```
http://localhost/site/page/test
```

problems begin when i start using i18n localization plugin. then it only works with this url:

```
http://localhost/site/en/news/page/test
```

I want the url to be wiout the `news` segment. What can I do to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work on any controller, with or without a language string

```
$route['^([a-z]{2})/(.*)'] = '$2';
$route['^([a-z]{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks normal to that it don't work anymore with the route cause it is missing the "/en/"

Did you try to put :

```
$route['en/page/test'] = 'news/page/1';
```

or

```
$route['en/page/test'] = 'en/news/page/1';
```

(I don't know the i18n plug)

If it works the solution might be in using a wildcard:

```
$route['(:any)/page/test'] = "news/page/1";
```

or

```
$route['(:any)/page/test'] = "$1/news/page/1";
```

(again i don't know the plug i18n plug works)